# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x -x}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan 2x -2x}{8x^3}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

In a post about [evaluating limits without L'Hopital's Rule or series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion), one of the limits used as an example was this:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x -x}{x^3}
$$

This expression was said to be equal to this:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan 2x -2x}{8x^3}
$$

I don't understand how this follows. I tried using $$\tan 2x\equiv\frac{2 \tan x}{1-\tan ^2x}$$ but it didn't seem to work. How can the two limits be shown to be equal to each other?

Comment: Substitute $y=2x$ in the first limit, and then, replace $y$ by $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a special case of $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(2x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it true that, in general, $\lim_{x \to 0}f(kx)=\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$, where $k$ is a constant?

Comment: I think you should put the question in comment in place of the actual question

Comment: @Joe If the limit exists & $k\ne0$, yes. There's an easy $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. The case $k=0$ exists iff $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The result follows considering $y=2x \to 0$ and more in general for any $f(x) \to 0$, not identically equal to $0$, we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x -x}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan (f(x)) -f(x)}{(f(x))^3}$$